# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env при чтении из сокета

Tags: java, сокет

По таймеру слежу за сообщениями от сокет сервера. Со временем программа вылетает. Помогает только периодический реконект сокета. Если закоментировать строку `int r = mSocket.getInputStream().read(buf);` то ошибки нет. Подскажите пожалуйста. Опыта в java нет совсем. Да и еще замечено что на новом телефоне с Android 7 не вылетает. Понимаю что идет утечка памяти. Грешил на `byte buf[] = new byte[1 * 512];` или `new Thread` Но нет. Именно `int r = mSocket.getInputStream().read(buf)`

Вот сам код:

```
new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 60, 10) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1 * 512];

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int r = mSocket.getInputStream().read(buf);
                    receiveSocket  = new String(buf, 0, r, "cp1251");
                    Log.d("Dima", receiveSocket);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.e("dim", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }).start();

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        this.start();
    }

}.start();
```

**UPDATE:**

Попробовал исправить так:

```
new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 60, 10) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1 * 512];

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        try {
            Log.d("Dima", "123");

            int r = mSocket.getInputStream().read(buf);
            String str  = new String(buf, 0, r, "cp1251");

            Log.d("Dima", str);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        this.start();
    }
}.start();
```

Сейчас не вылетает, но и из сокета не читает. Коннект с сервером есть. В лог выводится строка "123", но не переменная `str`. Ошибок не видать. Очень жду помощи.

Comment: Это обычный `java.net.Socket`?

Comment: Да. import java.net.Socket;

Comment: Сложно сходу сказать. Поставьте или breakpoint или покажите из-за какой ошибки вылетает приложение. Плюс я не понимаю, а зачем вы запускаете в потоке поток? Вот у вас есть таймер, он работает в оотдельном потоке. А вы на каждый тик создаете по потоку. Каждые 10 милисикунд. Возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: Убрал создание потока. Теперь действительно не вылетает. Но теперь вот такая ошибка при чтении сокета. И он не читается Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.Socket.getInputStream()' on a null object reference

Comment: Где и как объявлена переменная `receiveSocket`?

Comment: Это поле public String receiveSocket = ""; для class MainActivity